# Skyrim Thieves Guild Quests

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I completed the quest line that destroys Heimskr's house in Whiterun so I can't complete one of the jobs for the thieves guild. Will this hinder my game?

Edit: you need these quests to upgrade the thieves guild, so I am assuming I will never be able to fully upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not hinder your game.

As for the second part, what do you do since you can't go into his house to complete it?

Simple, cancel it with Vex/Delvin.  You will fail the quest that you are on, but it will give you no penalty, and you can just get another one.

A good trick is to sit there and cancel quests for cities that you have already done special quests for, and/or cancel until you have both quests in the same city.

See [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_(faction)#Special_Job_Quests) for more details on these types of quests.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know completing the other main quest line would have any impact on the other quests since I did the thieves guild quests last it seems. I have a ton of hours played. But I was just named GM of the thieves guild so I guess I'm all set. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Heimskyr's house is not part of any main Thieves Guild quest- only the radiant quests. These quests can be cancelled and replaced by talking to Vex or Delvin.